# Measure the amount of time it takes a server to respond to a GET request

Tags: java, dropwizard, response-time

I'd like to be able to see how long it takes a sql database to response to a get method in my app.  Currently, I'm measuring this by using System.currentTimeMillis() before and after the method runs:

```
public long responseTime(long start, long end) {
    long elapsed = end - start;
    return elapsed;
};

@GET
public getAllProfiles() {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    profileDAO.getAllProfiles();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsed = responseTime(start, end);
    return elapsed;
}
```

My concern, through, is that I'm measuring how long it takes for my method to run, rather than how long it takes for the server to respond to that method.  Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at a spy/debug driver? e.g. http://media.datadirect.com/download/docs/connectsqlxml/jdbcug/spy.htm. Caveat - I haven't used these in ages, not sure if they're for just debugging statements or also will give you timings.

Comment: You can use **dynatrace**, but its paid I guess.

Comment: Where do you receive the result from the Server? Is it a value being changed, or is it a function that gets called when the server returns a value?

Comment: If you use Dropwizard, as tag suggests, then it already has what you need: http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.1/docs/getting-started.html#metrics-for-metrics

Comment: The code will not compile. There is a return-type missing on `getAllProfiles()`. --- Do you need to get the response time via an REST-endpoint or would a log entry sufficient? If so, I would recommend benchmarking within `profileDAO.getAllProfiles()` and write the time to a log.

Answer (score 1):

One note on using `currentTimeMillis()`. Things change, but I've found that the millis are only updated every 10 millis or so. To see this, try creating a test class that loops 20 times and uses `Thread.sleep(1)`. You will see the same millis value around 10 times, then it will change to another value about 10 millis larger. Uses `nanoTime()` instead for durations.

As far as your question, create a test class that captures times and calls your method. I doubt you will see much difference, however.

Answer (score 1):

Dropwizard provides the [`@Timed` annotation](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.1/docs/manual/core.html#metrics) you can use on JAX-RS resource methods:

```
@Timed
@GET
public List<Profile> getAllProfiles() {
    List<Profile> profiles = profileDAO.getAllProfiles();
    return profiles;
}
```

The statistics will be available in the administration context of your Dropwizard application which is usually served on port `8081`.